# Python how to know properties/methods of objects

Tags: python, ide

Code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChat, PeerChannel

api_id = 123
api_hash = '0c0'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if(event.chat.title == ''):
        print(event.raw_text)
        

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Question:
So i have object(or i think that it is object) [event] i know that it has properties [.raw_text] and [.chat] how can i know what other fields it's has?

And because of python's "we don't need datatypes" i don't even understand where i must look...
I tried `print(event)` but there no [.raw_text] or [.chat].
But for example print(event.chat) print's [.title] (it's how i know about it).

Now i do it with downloaded repository and notepad++ "Search text in files in dir" and look on stuff that make any sense, in this case "objects-reference.rst".

You can say that i'm stupid but i never had similar issues with and other programing language.

I don't talk about convenient stuff like dropdowns(but i will appreciate it for VSCode or any other IDE) with props but about "where it in files" like c/c++/c#/java(almost) or and other OOP object has properties and methods or it's parent class (and so on) has it, but python code to chaotic to just look it up in file/s.

I don't have any problems when i work with popular and big libraries but when time comes to something small google/github can't give required information.

PS: This question is't about **Telethon** or **event** and it's properties but about python and how to work with it.

Comment: read the doc about the module used, or use `dir(var)`, some editors will autosuggest when you type `var.` if they can deduce the type of a `var`

Comment: @rioV8 Documentation it's privilege of big projects/libraries it's one of the reason why i never has this type of problem before.

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for "dir(var)", but there no "raw_text" in output.